# Global event bus using Vuex - always notify subscribers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've been using a global event bus for quite some time in Vue - something like `const bus = new Vue()`. Works fine, however, disposal of subscriptions can become quite verbose.

Let's say that I subscribe to an event in a component:

```
mounted() {
  bus.$on('some.event', callback)
}
```

I would have to keep track of the callback and dispose it properly in `beforeDestroy`. This can be somewhat simplified using a global mixin, but since I'm using `<keep-alive>`, I have to differentiate between subscriptions made in `mounted` and `activated` callback.

So I figured I would give Vuex a shot at managing this, since watchers are disposed by the framework. I came up with the proposal below.

Seems to work fine as long as objects or arrays are published. Primitive data doesn't seem to trigger the reactivity, despite being wrapped in the outer object, i.e. `{ data: 123 }`

I'm looking for alternative solutions regarding notifying the subscribers. All I've seen so far is the internal `notify` method, which doesn't feel very safe to use.

**eventstore.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const state = {
  events: {}
}

const actions = {
  publish({commit}, payload) {
    commit('publish_event', payload)
  }
}

const mutations = {
  publish_event(state, payload) {
    if(!state.events[payload.key]) {
      Vue.set(state.events, payload.key, { data: payload.data })
    } else {
      state.events[payload.key] = { data: payload.data }
    }
  }
}

const getters = {
  events: state => state.events
}

export default {
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
}
```

**globalmixin.js**

```
methods: {
  publish(key, data) {
    this.$store.dispatch('publish', { key, data })
  }
}
```

**somecomponent.vue**

```
function mapEventGetters(eventKeys) {
  return _.reduce(eventKeys, (result, current) => {
    result[current] = function() {
      return  _.get(this, `$store.getters.events.${current}.data`)
    }
    return result
  }, {})
}
```

```
computed: {
  ...mapEventGetters(['foo_bar'])
},
watch: {
  'foo_bar'(value) {
    console.log(`foo_bar changed to ${value}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is 'the internal notify method'? Are referring to watchers?

Comment: @RichardMatsen Here's an example: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/observer/array.js#L42

Comment: Ok, thanks. That does not appear in the API docs, so I agree might be dodgy to use ( `ob = this.__ob__` maybe it's an internal that could change?)

Comment: I just use computed properties in the component in lieu of watchers or explicit subscriptions. To get that deep reference on the store item, I would add a store getter that extracts the deep value.

Comment: @RichardMatsen Indeed, relying on internals seems like a bad idea :)

Comment: The computed property mechanism seems to be a real plus of Vue - it's fully reactive to store changes provided it sees all the right dependencies. In Angular Redux flavours use Rx subscriptions, but there's a memory leak problem if you don't explicitly unsubscribe. No such problem with Vue computed's.

Comment: You might try a computed with `let eventCount = Object.keys(this.$store.getters.events).length` as the first line. With a bit of luck that could react when new events are added.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I did a small update to the code. I make use of the wrapper object in conjunction with `Object.assign`. That way, the `data` property is mapped and its reference to the original object is intact, but since the property is reassigned, it triggers reacitivty.

Comment: Cool, that will do it. Encapsulates the extra bit of code too.

Comment: @Johan so did you found your solution?

Comment: @Darem Well, I would still like to know how to improve the notification triggering. For instance, this only works when objects or arrays are published. I have updated the question with my latest code

Comment: Hey Johan can you please create a codesanbox example, with the code you actually have, the expected behavior and what is actually happening? I will try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use deepCopy (for example `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`) to make sure data is reactive

```
const mutations = {
  publish_event(state, payload) {
    if(!state.events[payload.key]) {
      state.events[payload.key] = { data: payload.data }
    } else {
      state.events[payload.key] = Object.assign({}, state.events[payload.key], { data: payload.data })
    }
    state.events = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.events))
  }
}
```

In your component above, you're listening for `foo_bar` in watcher. [Vue watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) only work with component data (from `data`, `computed` or `vuex`).

You can redefine your data as `componentData` as below. You can use `mapGetters` for shorter syntax:

```
<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
  export default {
    ...mapGetters(['events']),
    computed: {
      componentData () {
        const eventKeys = ['foo_bar']
        return _.reduce(eventKeys, (result, current) => {
          result[current] = function() {
            return  _.get(this, `events.${current}.data`)
          }
          return result
        }, {})
      }
    },
    watch: {
      componentData: function (newVal, oldVal) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: "Vue watcher only work with component data (from data, computed or vuex).". `foo_bar` is a computed from vuex

Answer (score 2):

This API will break the Vuex's data flow which is the core concept of Vuex. The clients would able to mutate/read store state everywhere in Vuex.

Honestly this way is not needed to be implemented in the Vuex since it is just an event emitter. I suggest you to use some event emitter (probably empty Vue instance) in actions.

```
export const emitter = new Vue()

export default {
  // ...

  actions: {
    // should be called when the store is initialized
    // to observe events
    observe({ dispatch, commit }) {
      emitter.$on('some-event', () => {
        commit('someEvent')
      })

      emitter.$on('other-event', () => {
        dispatch('otherEvent')
      })
    },

    // notify some event in action
    notify({ state }) {
      emitter.$emit('notify', state.someValue)
    }
  }
}
```

It solve my problem once when I search in github. Mat be help you. Thanks!!

Comment: Nice answer here.  I had trouble this emitting the event from the component, I believe, because how the stores were namespaced.  Creating an action as a wrapper solved that problem.  Not sure why I did not think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Vue.set` on the object doesn't add observers / reactivity to the data inside the object. This requires an additional Vue.set

```
Vue.set(state.events, payload.key, {})
Vue.set(state.events[payload.key], 'data', payload.data)
```

You can also wrap this into a utility function which recursively sets data using `Vue.set`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this and let me know if reactivity was triggered in both of these situations?

First, remove this unnecessary wraping with outer object and send payload as simple key/value object with desired event key and data for this key:

```
{
  someKey: 123
}
```

As second, send some nested data:

```
{
  someKey: {
    nested: 'Value'
  }
}
```

But before this, change the mutation code as follows:

```
const mutations = {
  publish_event(state, payload) {
    // Instead of the previous code, just "patch"
    // the state.events with the payload content.
    state.events = { ...state.events, ...payload }
  }
}
```

And do not forget to improve your mapEventGetters function, as data are no more nested in "data" property.

PS: But personally I don't understand why to not use the Vuex with particular getters, because it works, it triggers the reactivity with primitive types:

***store/index.js***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

const state = {
  events: {}
}

const actions = {
  publish({commit}, payload) {
    commit('publish_event', payload)
  }
}

const mutations = {
  publish_event(state, payload) {
    state.events = { ...state.events, ...payload }
  }
}

const getters = {
  fooBar: state => state.events.fooBar || ''
}

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  actions,
  mutations,
  getters
})
```

***main.js***

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '@/App'
import store from '@/store'

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('main')
```

***some component***

```
<template>
  <span>{{ fooBar }}</span>
</template>

import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'SomeComponent',

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['fooBar'])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['publish'])
  },

  created () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      publish({
        fooBar: 123
      })
    }, 3000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. "But personally I don't understand why to not use the Vuex with particular getters, because it works, it triggers the reactivity with primitive types". It doesn't if the value remains the same between two publishes

Comment: And? Where is the difference? Your mutation rewrites data for particular key too.